Make mypy ignore errors related to an installed external package
I have an installed package foo which is defined as typed (has the py.typed file) but the types are incomplete leading to the error:
bar.py:6: error: Module "foo" has no attribute "Communication"  [attr-defined]
other_bar.py:6: error: Module "foo" has no attribute "Calibration"  [attr-defined]
[...]

I would like to completely ignore the analysis of the package foo to no longer have these errors,  as if the package was missing
I have tried to add in pyproject.toml
[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = ["foo", "foo.*"]
ignore_errors = "True"

but it does nothing. My understanding is that on mypy's side, the errors come from bar and other_bar module so the override does nothing.

Yes, your understanding is fully correct, and you cannot do what you're asking for (at least to best of my knowledge). This was asked before here. Your best bet would be just rm your/venv/lib/python3.X/site-packages/foo/py.typed in CI before running mypy.
